# Error:In displaying the contents from the databse on to the webpage (CMS site)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I'm working on a CMS website, I have got one issue which I'm trying to fix it from saturday, but im unable to know why such error is coming. I'm getting an error like this

> Error: A PHP Error was encountered
>       Severity: Notice
>       Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>       Filename: views/services.php

Here I'm using two values one is `results` and another is `results`, but I'm still not getting why it's showing error as Trying to get property of non-object. more over I used the same concept in my another page, which is working fine but I don't know why I'm getting error like this here. Please can anyone guide me in this.

**This is my Home.php(Controller)**

```
    //-----------Services page-------------

        public function services()  
        {  
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->view('header');
            $data['results'] = $this->Contact_model->service_us_getvalue();
            $data['resultss'] = $this->Contact_model->service_us_getvalue1();
            $this->load->view('services',$data); 
            $this->load->view('footer');                    
        }
```

**This is my Contact_model.php**

```
    //--------Service----------


    //query to select the different rows
    function service_us_getvalue()
    {
        return  $this->db->get('service_us')->row();
    }

    function service_us_getvalue1()
    {
        return  $this->db->get("service_us WHERE type='Section_2'")->result();
    }
```

**Service.php**

```
    //   This is how it looks when the website is in static mode this one I'm trying to convert dynamic.  

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="media">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="media-left">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Web Development</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum erat libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="media-left">
            <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Responsive Design</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum erat libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="media-left">
            <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Bootstrap Themes</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus interdum erat libero, pulvinar tincidunt leo consectetur eget.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>-->

    <?php
        if (isset($resultss))
        {
            echo $resultss->description; 
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use `row()` instead of `result()` in `service_us_getvalue1` method

*Your model method `service_us_getvalue1` should be like this :*

```
function service_us_getvalue1()
{
  $this->db->where('type' , 'Section_2');
  return  $this->db->get("service_us")->row();
}
```

Comment: change `result()` to `row()` and try again see my answer pls

Comment: Thank you sir it's working. Thanks for guiding once again.

Comment: Sir why I did not got the output when I used - >result??

Comment: What might be reason?

Comment: result() gives an array of objects while row() gives single row,

Comment: read this in details : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: ok sir i will go through the link. anyways thank you for guiding sir

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help you

```
<?php
        if (isset($resultss))
        {
            echo $resultss['description']; 
        }
    ?>
```